# ggplot with facet_wrap and how to correctly label axis from another coumn in data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, facet-wrap

I have dataframe of expenses, and want to make a lollipop plot with the expenses in monetary order. I want to facet the plot by year, and to colour the variable of interest so it is highlighted. I can sort of get it going, but not all at the same time.

I use a dummy variable for the axis as when I otherwise plot by "type" the magic of ggplot rearranges the axis alphabetically (I lose the "dollars" ordering).

The data input$grouper is for an input selector in shinyR. Ultimately it selects one of the "type" levels. For this exercise, I set it manually to a static value:

```
input <- data.frame(grouper="misc")
```

The following code will colour the points correctly, and plots things in the right order, but does not use the correct labels:

```
ggplot(pld3, aes(x=dummy, y=dollars))+
  scale_x_discrete(aes(breaks = dummy,
                       labels = type))+
  geom_point(aes(color=ifelse(type %in% input$grouper, "orange", "grey"),
  size=ifelse(type %in% input$grouper, 5,2)), show.legend = F) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=dummy, xend=dummy, y=0, yend=dollars))+
  scale_color_identity()+
  facet_wrap(.~years, scales="free_y")+
  coord_flip()
```

This next code produces the correct labels, but the coloured points are incorrect:

```
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = pld3$dummy,
                       labels = pld3$type)+
  geom_point(aes(color=ifelse(type %in% input$grouper, "orange", "grey"),
                 size=ifelse(type %in% input$grouper, 5,2)), show.legend = F) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=dummy, xend=dummy, y=0, yend=dollars))+
  scale_color_identity()+
  facet_wrap(.~years, scales="free_y")+
  coord_flip()
```

It is possible I have the logic of this all upsidedown....

the data:

```
pld3 <- structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 14L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 5L, 
14L, 13L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
14L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 13L, 16L, 1L, 17L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 
11L, 10L, 18L, 14L, 4L, 9L, 17L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 14L, 11L, 
9L, 18L, 16L, 4L), levels = c("gifts", "distilling", "health", 
"travel", "out", "work", "bikes", "booze", "misc", "rent", "food", 
"twokids", "farm", "house", "paid twokids", "car", "garden", 
"bills"), class = "factor"), years = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023
), dollars = c(30.4508882916998, 97.2312363516539, 67.27857386088, 
3.40714434394613, 82.1119976679329, 66.1653377907351, 13.7356115481816, 
38.5452354955487, 98.8311156637501, 87.60709310323, 19.9229170964099, 
63.8904112470336, 63.1930333869532, 71.1441945903935, 33.8642323177774, 
46.0929368177895, 32.7911926973611, 4.1690314640291, 91.6797045858111, 
5.69200977962464, 3.44765204098076, 38.0464599244297, 91.6876729594078, 
21.4428106914274, 88.5851034789812, 18.2466823637951, 63.0068064918742, 
39.8931721111294, 35.3828299364541, 7.46235140180215, 39.678023626795, 
63.4598906219471, 57.7810981469229, 63.1811229162849, 22.1307350744028, 
77.6383776273578, 14.9168002144434, 33.5137796991039, 30.6489827609621, 
44.8925060238689, 49.2971150246449, 99.6876992292237, 13.3659518382046, 
80.6224727097433, 55.3629546693992, 67.7745414755773, 66.7366110722069, 
76.5307065290399, 96.0733813908882, 1.80299972440116, 98.368068369804, 
29.0037194518372, 57.7083215517923, 5.08068777737208, 32.8412234601565, 
13.9458251157776, 45.9616257676389, 48.4158545704558, 16.1542183584534, 
35.4940443637315, 58.7527071500663, 33.0197566482238, 47.9688329054043, 
12.217799274018, 11.3902374280151, 67.793595720781, 52.1694662619848, 
48.6166335390881, 44.6549816404004, 93.7184616387822, 67.6560284914449, 
77.0413119411096, 91.0595601066016, 78.0627505476587, 99.963882842334, 
80.5387081373483, 95.406732073985, 49.6403462125454, 15.3783161661122, 
75.6729182200506, 32.8654465128202), dummy = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -81L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to reorder your dataset by `years` and `dummy`, add a helper column as the interaction of `dummy` and `type` and then use `formats::fct_inorder` to convert the helper to a factor with the levels ordered according to the order of the dataset. This helper could then be mapped on `x` or as I do below on `y` (I switched `x` for `y` and dropped the `coord_flip`). As a second step we clean up the labels inside `scale_y_discrete` to get rid of the `dummy` part aka the numbers:

Note: Similar to `scale_color_identity` I added a `scale_size_identity`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

pld3 <- pld3 |>
  arrange(years, dummy) |>
  mutate(
    order = paste(dummy, type, sep = "."),
    order = forcats::fct_inorder(order)
  )

ggplot(pld3, aes(y = order, x = dollars)) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = ~ gsub("^\\d+\\.", "", .x)
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(
    color = ifelse(type %in% input$grouper, "orange", "grey"),
    size = ifelse(type %in% input$grouper, 6, 1)
  ), show.legend = F) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = order, yend = order, x = 0, xend = dollars)) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_size_identity() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ years, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(y = "type")
```

[image]